# Would this grain bill make "true" Irish Red Ale?

Tags: all-grain, recipe-formulation

I have a problem. I've read BJCP description of Irish Red Ale, and many recipes and... they don't quite match. Some recipes use crystal malt. Some does not. Most use roasted barley. Some do not. Many use monachium malt. Many do not. And I feel lost.

How about this grain bill?

- 3kg Pale Ale
- 1kg monach 2
- 500g CaraRed
- 150g roasted barley / black malt

Is this honest to the style? And, if hopped and fermented properly, would it taste like one?

By Brewtarget, it looks like OG, FG, ABV, IBU and color in EBC would be in style, but that's not the most important part. Would it be red? And would it taste properly?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is on topic, and [I've got no reply on meta](http://meta.homebrew.stackexchange.com/q/411/12577), so posting anyway.

Comment: Your best friend right now is page 26 (PDF page 40) of the new 2015 BJCP guidelines: http://www.bjcp.org/docs/2015_Guidelines_Beer.pdf  That'll get you 95% of the way there.

Answer (score 1):

I've done the Morebeer Irish Red Ale kit. Was very simular to a couple commercial examples noted in bjcp 2015 . Here's the recipe for 5gal.

- 10lb 2-Row
- 1lb Crystal 120L
- 8oz Abbey
- 8oz Caramunich
- 2oz Black Roasted
- 2oz Special B
- 1.5oz northern brewer 60min
- 2oz Willamette 1min

WLP004 Irish Ale Yeast

Comment: Seems my Munich and red crystal should be roughly equivalent. If much simpler. I think I'll stick to my original idea for simplicity, risking a little drift. It shouldn't drift far away from original, I hope.

Comment: @Mołot yea I don't see why not. Let us know how it does. 

Comment: You confirmed that munich-like tastes are expected there, so... :) In a month or two it'll be drinkable.